# react-router-dom v6 NavLink and MUI ListItem not working with className

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have a problem using MUI with react-router-dom v6.

```
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
<List key={index}>
  <ListItem
     component={NavLink}
     sx={{
       color: '#8C8C8C',
     }}
     to={'/home'}
     className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? classes.activeLink : undefined)
     >
     <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
   <ListItemText primary='Home'/>
 </ListItem>
</List>
```

`className` not working and show error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'
The expected type comes from property 'className' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { button?: false | undefined; } & ListItemBaseProps & { components?: { Root?: ElementType<any> | undefined; } | undefined; componentsProps?: { ...; } | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all, and here is my solution

```
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyNavLink = React.forwardRef<any, any>((props, ref) => (
  <NavLink
    ref={ref}
    to={props.to}
    className={({ isActive }) => `${props.className} ${isActive ? props.activeClassName : ''}`}
  >
    {props.children}
  </NavLink>
));

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    activeLink: {
      backgroundColor: '#19ABC0',
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      borderRadius: 8,
      '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        stroke: '#FFFFFF',
        fill: '#19ABC0',
      },
    },
  })
);

function Sidebar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <List>
        <ListItem
          component={MyNavLink}
          sx={{
            color: '#8C8C8C',
          }}
          to={'/home'}
          activeClassName={classes.activeLink}
        >
          <ListItemIcon sx={{ stroke: '#8C8C8C', fill: '#FFFFFF' }}></ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={'Home'} />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      <List>
        <ListItem
          component={MyNavLink}
          sx={{
            color: '#8C8C8C',
          }}
          to={'/dashboard'}
          activeClassName={classes.activeLink}
        >
          <ListItemIcon sx={{ stroke: '#8C8C8C', fill: '#FFFFFF' }}></ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={'Dashboard'} />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
className={({ isActive }) => `${props.className} ${isActive ? props.activeClassName : ''}`}
```

To use MUI's className and add NavLink's active class.

Answer (score 9):

## Issue

The issue is that the `className` prop is for the `ListItem`, not the component you've specified to be rendered. It's not an extraneous prop and isn't passed along to the `NavLink` component.

## Solution

- https://mui.com/guides/routing/#link
- https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/7956

The solution appears to be to create a custom navlink component with the dynamic `className` prop enclosed. Pass your dynamic `className` function on a different prop, say `activeClassName`, and pass this to the `NavLink`'s `className` prop internally.

Example:

```
import { NavLink as NavLinkBase } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const NavLink = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <NavLinkBase
    ref={ref}
    {...props}
    className={props.activeClassName}
  />
));
```

...

```
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import { NavLink } from '../path/to/NavLink';

...

<List key={index}>
  <ListItem
    component={NavLink}
    activeClassName={({ isActive }) =>
      isActive ? classes.activeLink : undefined
    }
    sx={{ color: '#8C8C8C' }}
    to="/home"
  >
    <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary='Home' />
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-v6-navlink-and-mui-listitem-not-working-with-classname]

Answer (score 4):

The ***className*** property in a ListItem can only accept a string
However on a NavLink, you can define a function that has its state (active or inactive)

You can create a CustomNavLink component that gets the properties from the ListItemButton (using forwardRef) and also have different styles based on its state

If you want to preserve the styling of mui's ListItemButton make sure you add its appropriate [mui css classname](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item/#css) to the ***className*** property of the NavLink.
You can then add the different styling classes for whether it's active or not.

```
const CustomNavLink = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <NavLink
    ref={ref}
    {...props}
    className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? props.className + ' Mui-selected' : props.className)}
    end
  />
));
```

---

Make sure you use the CustomNavLink as the component for ListItemButton and add the ***to*** property which will be forwarded to the NavLink

```
<List>
  <ListItem>
    <ListItemButton
      component={CustomNavLink}
      to="/"
    >
      <ListItemIcon><ListIcon /></ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary='Home' />
    </ListItemButton>
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

Comment: This solved my related problem of how to render a selected Drawer item as "selected" based on the behavior of the `NavLink` component from `ReactRouter`. Although this remains magical to me, it is at least magic that works -- after I've spent a long time thrashing at alternatives. I've upvoted this, and at least for me it is the answer to my own question that brought me here. Kudo's to @Tkivai for posting this.

Answer (score 1):

It's bothering me this couple of days..
and what I found to be the least complicated solution is to add !important;
to the CSS of .active

```js
  <Button component={NavLink} to="/home">
  Home
  </Button>
```

```css
  .active {
    color: #F07DEA !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `useMatch` hook from react

```
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import { Link as RouterLink, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

interface TopNavLinkProps {
    to: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const TopNavLink = ({ to = '/', children }: TopNavLinkProps) => {
    // "/*" at the end is to make sure that routes like 
   //'/about/company' and '/about/team' will still match the top nav item 
    // '/about'
  const isActive = useMatch({ path: `${to}/*`, end: true }); 
    
    return (
        <Link
            variant="button"
            to={to}
            sx={{ textDecoration: isActive ? 'underline' : 'none' }}
            component={RouterLink}
        >
            {children}
        </Link>
    );
};
```

After that use `TopNavLink` component and it will be `route-aware`

```
<nav>
 <TopNavLink to="/">Home</TopNavLink>
 <TopNavLink to="/about">About</TopNavLink>
</nav>
```